# Webservice Response Ends with --UUID

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am using cxf framework in order to expose some web services.
When i tested it using soap-ui, it works great. But one of our customers that uses different soap client complains that the message ends with:

> /soap:Envelope>
>
> --uuid:91c5694a-93f5-404c-ab2b-8c220b7f289f--

I searched the web, and i found that this line apears not only in our system. But I couldn't figure out whether this suffix is valid and well-formed, or not.

Is there any reference that document this issue?
Is it really valid?
How can I remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have MTOM enabled on the server side.   In that case, the SOAP message is wrapped in mime wrappers (which is per spec).   The --uuid thing is a marker of a mime part.   If the client is having issues with those, then it sounds like that client cannot handle MTOM.  You COULD turn MTOM off for those clients.

Comment: I could not find any documentation about "--uuid: ... " section even in the MTOM spec. Could you please refer me to a place that gives an example of web service response with this MTOM?